# Plot function only plots one amount in this dataframe. What could be the reason?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have created a long format dataframe

```
  Category           Amount
1    Angry 0.00000010230325
2     Fear 0.00000007393743
3    Happy 0.99942147731781
4  Neutral 0.00057571416255
5      Sad 0.00000002021321
6 Surprise 0.00000260657316
```

And the code is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
# There are plenty of ways to reshape the data frame,
# but I think `tidyr::gather()` is the easiest
dfr_long <- gather(dfr, key = "Category", value = "Amount")
ggplot(data = dfr_long, aes(x = Category, y = Amount)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

However, as you see in the image, only Happy gets plotted and the rest are all in same level. I even tried to change the ylim to c(-1,0.99) but the plot still looks the same. How can I fix this?

[image: plot]

Comment: The value for happy is greater than 0.999. All other values are less than 0.001.  You cannot expect to see those small values in a plot that is scaled 0 to 1. The other values should be less than 1/1000 the height of happy.

Comment: @neilfws I tried to change the ylim values but it still wouldnt plot. Is it not possible at all to plot such values?

Comment: They _are_ being plotted. They're just minuscule. You can try `+ scale_y_continuous(trans = "sqrt")` but you then need to _make sure you note the transformation in the plot labels_.

Comment: The issue is the scale, as @G5W pointed out. You could try a log scale, _e.g._ `+ scale_y_log10()`, but then bars will not be appropriate, you could try points instead.

Comment: @neilfws or multiply `Amount` by ~`100000000` and use `log10` and change the Y labels and add alot of notes about the transformation :-) @codeybanks we don't really know what these values represent but I'd suggest the values of the other categories are so small that they may be nigh irrelevant.

Comment: I think it comes down to: is plotting the data adding any value? Are you getting insight from visualisation? If not, the values may as well be in a table.

Comment: Yes. the output is insightful. But I wanted to represent it in the form of plots.

Comment: You might want to read the answer and delete that comment afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your claim against my comment was woefully incorrect:

```
read.table(text="Category           Amount
    Angry 0.00000010230325
     Fear 0.00000007393743
    Happy 0.99942147731781
  Neutral 0.00057571416255
      Sad 0.00000002021321
 Surprise 0.00000260657316", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> dfr

ggplot(data = dfr, aes(x = Category, y = 100000000*Amount)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

[image]

NOTE that ^^ *seriously misrepresents the data* and requires *a ton of labeling* to make sure your readers do not misinterpret it.

This:

```
ggplot(data = dfr, aes(x = Category, y = Amount)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "sqrt")
```

[image]

is *somewhat* better but still requires you to do a substantial amount of labeling to ensure the data is not being misrepresented.

This:

```
options(scipen = 999)

dplyr::arrange(dfr, desc(Amount)) %>% 
  mutate(Category = factor(Category, levels = Category)) %>%
  mutate(txt_col = dplyr::case_when(
    Category == "Happy" ~ "white",
    TRUE ~ "black"
  )) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = 1)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Amount), color = "white", size=0.125) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Amount, color = I(txt_col)), size=2.5) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(direction = -1) +
  coord_equal() +
  labs(
    x = NULL, y = NULL
  ) + 
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc(grid="") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

is an alternate way to show the data but it's no more effective than a basic, ordered table would be IMO.